# Overlapping one Div onto Another

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get a very specific look for my navigation. I want the background to be a solid image and I want the links to be separated text images that float above it to make it look like a piece. I've got it aligned perfectly, the issue is that I can't get the links to appear above the background. The code is below:

```
<div id=Navigation>
    <div id="NavBar">
        <img src="Site Images/Navigation/Nav_BG.png"/>
    </div><!--Nav Bar -->
    <div id="NavLinks">
        <a href="x"><img src="" /><a>
        <a href="x"><img src="" /><a>
        <a href="x"><img src="" /><a>
        <a href="x"><img src="" /><a>
        <a href="x"><img src="" /><a>
        <a href="x"><img src="" /><a>
    </div><!-- End of Navlinks -->
</div><!-- End of Navigation Div -->
```

The CSS is

```
#Navigation {
    height: 810px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
}

#NavBar {
    position: absolute;
    z: 2; /* What is `z`? */
}

#NavLinks{
    float: none;
    z: 1; /* What is `z`? */
}
```

I tried the `z` attribute but it's not working. I know that something is wrong. The `div id="Navigation"` must float left, or the `div id="content"` (not added here) won't be next to it.

Comment: What is `z`? `z-index`?

Comment: Z is the script that I got from both a reference book and from w3schools. Changing it to z-index didn't change anything. But at least it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would delete the background div and set the background with css like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_links">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_links{
    background-image: url('path'); /*Put here the path to your background image*/
}
```

Maybe if you add more information about your problem I can give you better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the values of z-index in css of rules

```
#NavBar
```

and

```
#NavLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is at CSS attribute `z` that you used. I can find anything about this, so I guess you mean `z-index`.

Try to change to the CSS below:

```
#Navigation {
    height: 810px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
}

#NavBar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2 /* `z-index` instead of `z` */
}

#NavLinks{
    float: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It should give you the expected result.